# Retrieving Token Payloads During Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index defined like the following, which uses the [delimited payload token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-delimited-payload-tokenfilter.html) and stores payloads along with tokens:

```http
PUT text_payloads
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "term_vector": "with_positions_payloads",
        "analyzer": "payload_delimiter"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "payload_delimiter": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [ "delimited_payload" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With a document in that index like such:

```http
POST text_payloads/_doc/1
{
  "text": "the|0 brown|3 fox|4 is|0 quick|10"
}
```

I can get the payloads using the `_termvectors` api:

```http
GET text_payloads/_termvectors/1
{
  "fields": [ "text" ],
  "payloads": true
}
```

This returns the following result:

```json
{
  "_index": "text_payloads",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "took": 0,
  "term_vectors": {
    "text": {
      "field_statistics": {
        "sum_doc_freq": 5,
        "doc_count": 1,
        "sum_ttf": 5
      },
      "terms": {
        "brown": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 1,
              "payload": "QEAAAA=="
            }
          ]
        },
        "fox": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 2,
              "payload": "QIAAAA=="
            }
          ]
        },
        "is": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 3,
              "payload": "AAAAAA=="
            }
          ]
        },
        "quick": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 4,
              "payload": "QSAAAA=="
            }
          ]
        },
        "the": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 0,
              "payload": "AAAAAA=="
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I use the `_search` endpoint instead, using a `match_phrase` query and a highlighter:

```
POST text_payloads/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "text": "brown fox"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": ["<mark>"],
    "post_tags": ["</mark>"],
    "encoder": "html",
    "fields": {
      "text": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following result:

```json
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.5753642,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "text_payloads",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "text": "the|0 brown|3 fox|4 is|0 quick|10"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "text": [
            "the|0 <mark>brown|3</mark> <mark>fox|4</mark> is|0 quick|10"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This works, and I can parse the payloads out of the highlighted search result, but I'd rather ElasticSearch give me the payloads in some sort of structured format. It would be even better if ElasticSearch then highlighted the result and didn't include said payloads in the result but just gave me the plain text.

Is anything like this possible with ElasticSearch? Or should I stick to parsing the result with the payloads embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'd rather ElasticSearch give me the payloads in some sort of structured format.

The term vectors and multi term vectors APIs is the way to go here.

> Is anything like this possible with ElasticSearch?

Not at the moment unless you want to implement it as a plugin.

> Or should I stick to parsing the result with the payloads embedded?

I think that's the simplest way to deal with it. There is not much support for handling payloads outside of plugins. Highlighter is also oblivious of payload delimited format so for a highlighter `brown|3` is just a part of input text that gets indexed as `brown`, the highlighter finds `brown` and highlights the corresponding text based on the stored positions or additional analysis. Which means it will highlight `brown|3`. If you don't want to remove payloads you need to index this field twice - with and without payload and highlight the version without payload.

Using information discovered by the highlighter to find the corresponding parts of term vectors is also tricky. Internally highlighter knows exactly the location of the original token but it doesn't give this information back to the client, only the result of applying this information to the original string. There is [almost a decade old issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5736) where users are asking to enable this.

Comment: > The term vectors and multi term vectors APIs is the way to go here.

Is it possible to get the specific term vectors through the term vector API that are referenced in the search results?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "term vector API that are referenced in the search results". When search is done individual shards send back an internal IDs of top N results and their sort keys. All other information the led to result selection is gone by this time. Highlighting is reverse engineering the reason for the match. If you mean the result of highlighting the answer is basically "No", I added some explanation to the end of my answer.

Comment: Great, thank you! Sounds like the best thing to do would just be to parse the payloaded text from the search result.